# How can I download a file in Firefox Webextension without using chrome.downloads.download?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

in my chrome extension I use `chrome.downloads.download` to initiate a file download, but in firefox Web Extensions this method is not yet implemented (as seen [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245597)).

Is there any other way I can initiate a file download from within my firefox add-on?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind I used html5's `download` attribute.

I create < a>'s using:

`var a = document.createElement("a");`

and then add the download property like so:

`a.download = rowData.url+".mp4";`

Clicking the `a` link within my web extension firefox add-on now downloads the file instead of opening it within its view.

Comment: Did you just do an a.click() and it worked out of the box?  I'm struggling to download a file generated the the WebExtension (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139329/how-do-i-programmatically-download-a-file-created-on-the-file-with-a-firefox-web)

Comment: I only used an addEventListener to the a tag.