# How do I programmatically download a file created on the file with a Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to port a Chrome Extension that programmatically creates and downloads a file to a Firefox WebExtension, using Firefox 45.0.1.

This is the Javascript code:

```javascript
  text = '{"greeting":"Hello, World!"}';
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var file = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/json'});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = 'hello.world';   // Filename  
  a.click();                    // Trigger download
```

All lines seem to execute fine, but no file is downloaded (I put a `console.log()` after the `a.click()`).

As of now there is no chrome.downloads API in Firefox WebExtensions.

Is there any incompatibility with Firefox in the code above? Is there any other alternative to programmatically download a file using a Firefox WebExtension?

Comment: Firefox does have a `chrome.downloads` API, but unfortunately it does not support downloading `blob:`-URLs due to this bug: https://bugzil.la/1287347

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, would be to add an event listener to the a tag.

```
text = '{"greeting":"Hello, World!"}';
var a = document.createElement('a');
var file = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/json'});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.download = 'hello.world';   // Filename  
a.addEventListener('click', dlLinkClicked);


function dlLinkClicked(e){
    var link = e.currentTarget.href;
    var filename = e.currentTarget.download;

    /*downloadVidWithChromeApi downloads using the chrome download API, 
    otherwise returns false and starts downloading the file 
    using the html5 download - you don't have to do anything else*/

    if(downloadVidWithChromeApi(link, filename)){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function downloadVidWithChromeApi(link, fileName){
    if(chrome.downloads && chrome.downloads.download){
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: link,
            saveAs: false,
            filename: fileName // Optional
        });
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Notice that I use the `downloadVidWithChromeApi` function like so, to check if chrome.downloads is supported.

Therefore this code can run in both firefox, chrome, AND opera web extensions AS IS.

Comment: This code does not seem to trigger the download automatically.  I also tried it with `a.click()` after the `a.addEventListener('click', dlLinkClicked);` line.  I am using Firefox 45.0.1 on Windows (latest release for regular users).  Is this the same Firefox you are using?

Comment: Or, is there a permission I am missing in my manifest.json to get the download? For my Firefox WebExtension, I only have `tabs` permission, which is unrelated to this code anyway. As far a I know, the `chrome.downloads` API will not be in Firefox until Firefox 47 so I do not think that the `download` permission will be available in Firefox 45.

Comment: Those are my permissions `"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "*://*/*",
  "downloads"
 ],`  Perhaps if you add the `downloads` permission you'll be able to `a.click();` to trigger it?

Comment: On second thought, perhaps you try to do `a.click();` before the element has loaded? Try to wrap your code with: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
//code here
};` OR `window.onload = function onWindowLoad() { //code here }`